# Why ASP.NET Controls defined in mark up already created on Page_PreInit life cycle event

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I read [Microsoft's article on ASP.Net Page Life Cycle events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). It confused on one thing. When Page_PreInit gets called, all the controls' Init method is not yet called. When I setup a test project, I observed a different behavior. In the mark up, I created asp label and button controls and set certain properties such as Text. I put a break point at the beginning of Page_PreInit. When break point got hit, I checked if the controls got created or not by referring to them by their Ids in the Watch window. They all existed and none returned null. Then I checked the Text property and it was what I set in the mark up. So doesn't this contradict what Microsoft says? If this is the case what do Controls' Init method do if they are already initialized? Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 1):

> I created asp label and button controls and set certain properties
>   such as Text. ... Then I checked the Text property and it was what I set
>   in the mark up.

If you set property value at ***Design Time***, they are in control tree so properties are available in all events.

However, if you add a TextBox and a user clicks on submit, **TextBox Text Property** only start available at **Page_Load** event.

*The reason is that Page_Load is the place where properties are loaded with information recovered from view state and control state.*

## Look at this example

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Name" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton"
    Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

[image]

### After Postback,

[image]

[image]

Notice that you can only retrieve TextBox value at Page_Load event.

[image]

Comment: But what does Init do for Controls then? I thought whether in design time or not, Init was the event where Controls initialized their properties.

Comment: You can use ***Init*** event to manipulate ViewState. Normally, we use ***Init*** event to reload dynamically added controls.

Comment: I talk about Control's own Init event. Not the one I can implement.

Comment: Microsoft article defines PreInit as "Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins." If initialization didn't start yet, then how can even design time properties be available on the control in PreInit?

Comment: `how can even design time properties be available on the control in PreInit` The key is **ViewState**. **Some Properties** *(including Design Time properties)* are stored in **ViewState** -  look at **Getter and Setter** of a control's source code. Notice that **ViewState** is available in all events.

Comment: Microsoft doc on Control Init event says "Occurs when the server control is initialized, which is the first step in its lifecycle." This says the first step in its life cycle, but your previous comment says otherwise. I understand all about view state and all, but I don't see how you associate my question with it. If you look at the picture in the Microsoft link, it doesn't show any step about View State prior to PreInit event.

Comment: If you talk that way, a lot of thing happens even before ***Init*** event *such as calling constructor*. Let think about simple class - if you set a property value at design time, it is available at any method even inside constructor. If you want to test it, you can create a **Server Control**, and look at design time property value inside **constructor**.

Comment: As the last thing, then what is meant by control initialization? It's misleading. When I read Microsoft article, initializing control seemed to mean control being created and all it properties getting set according to mark up values.

Comment: By Control Initialization, I meant each Controls's Init method being called. And this happens after Page_PreInit. When does the Control initialization you mentioned in previous comment happen?

Comment: I deleted the above comment; it was misleading. `initializing control seemed to mean control being created and all it properties getting set according to mark up values` Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Then it doesn't make sense that I am able to access property values defined in mark up in Page_PreInit method since Init for individual controls didn't run yet, but you were telling me otherwise. So again I conclude that Microsoft article is ambiguous.